# Nodejs File Permissions

Tags: file, node.js, file-permissions

In Node the `fs.stat` method returns an `fs.Stats` object right, and I can get the file permission through the `fs.Stats.mode` property.

Here is a real output from both node and shell for the same directories:

```
node  shell
17407 d rwx rwx rwt
16877 d rwx r-x r-x
16749 d r-x r-x r-x
16832 d rwx --- ---
```

I need to know how to parse the `fs.Stats.mode` number to get the permissions.

## Answer

The number is in octal numeric system, after converting to decimal looks like this:

```
17407 41777 d rwx rwx rwt
16877 40755 d rwx r-x r-x
16749 40555 d r-x r-x r-x
16832 40777 d rwx --- ---
```

And the convertion from octal to decimal system is like this:

```
parseInt(stat.mode.toString(8), 10)
```

Great tutorial on file permissions in linux - https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions

Comment: Unfortunately tuxfiles.org appears to be gone now

Comment: Just updated the link. Hopefully this will stay longer.

Comment: For `rwx` can do `stat.mode & 0o777`. If it's the string you want then do `(stat.mode & 0o777).toString(8)`.

Answer (score 22):

```
var checkPermission = function (file, mask, cb){
    fs.stat (file, function (error, stats){
        if (error){
            cb (error, false);
        }else{
            cb (null, !!(mask & parseInt ((stats.mode & parseInt ("777", 8)).toString (8)[0])));
        }
    });
};
```

**canExecute()**:

```
checkPermission (<path>, 1, cb);
```

**canRead()**:

```
checkPermission (<path>, 4, cb);
```

**canWrite()**:

```
checkPermission (<path>, 2, cb);
```

Comment: Why Node-FileUtils don't support group and other permissions

Comment: Because every OS manages the permissions in a different way, so I prefer to only support user permissions.

Answer (score 1):

The number format is platform dependent, so you can't, reliably.

When NodeJs starts exposing the underlying `S_ISDIR` function and the `S_IRUSR` and similar constants, you can.

Some information on the stat format: http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat

Comment: I know that but for now I wanted to get the permissions only for linux system. Again the man page in different styling - http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/stat.2.html