# How do I check if a file is executable in node.js?

Tags: node.js, filesystems

How do I check if a file is executable in node.js?

Maybe something like

```
fs.isExecutable(function (isExecutable) {

})
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would use the `fs.stat` call for that.

The `fs.stat` call returns a [fs.Stats](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats) object.

In that object is a `mode` attribute.  The mode will tell you if the file is executable.

In my case, I created a file and did a `chmod 755 test_file` and then ran it through the following code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
test = fs.statSync('test_file');
console.log(test);
```

What I got for `test.mode` was 33261.

[This link](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=323977) is helpful for converting `mode` back to unix file permissions equivalent.

Comment: There’s also a very helpful module [mode-to-permissions](https://github.com/mmalecki/mode-to-permissions) – if you don’t want to mess with details.

Comment: right, I would upvote this, if it explained how to find out a file was executable given the mode

Comment: They've since added constants like `fs.constants.S_IXUSR` to the stdlib BTW: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69897809/895245

Answer (score 19):

Another option that relies only on the built-in `fs` module is to use either [fs.access](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_access_path_mode_callback) or [fs.accessSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_accesssync_path_mode). This method is easier than getting and parsing the file mode. An example:

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.access('./foobar.sh', fs.constants.X_OK, (err) => {
    console.log(err ? 'cannot execute' : 'can execute');
});
```

Comment: read/write, or execute? we need to be able to execute the file

Comment: Good point. I updated the example to match the specific question.

Answer (score 3):

**`fs.stat` named bitmask mode check with `fs.constants.S_IXUSR`**

Node.js appears to have added those since https://stackoverflow.com/a/16258627/895245 had been written, you can now do:

```
const fs = require('fs');

function isExec(p) {
  return !!(fs.statSync(p).mode & fs.constants.S_IXUSR)
}

console.log(isExec('/usr/bin/ls'))
console.log(isExec('/dev/random'))
```

Of course, this highlights the fact that it is a bit harder to do an actual "can I execute this file check", since we have three such constants as documented at https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v17.x/api/fs.html#file-mode-constants:

- `fs.constants.S_IXUSR`: user
- `fs.constants.S_IXGRP`: group
- `fs.constants.S_IXOTH`: other

as per:

```
man 2 chmod
```

so a full check with `stat` requires checking if you match the file owner, or are part of a group.

So perhaps it is better to just use the cumbersome raise API of `fs.accessSync` as mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41929624/895245 :

```
const fs = require('fs');

function isExec(p) {
  try {
    fs.accessSync(p, fs.constants.X_OK)
    return true
  } catch (e) {
    return false
  }
}

console.log(isExec('/usr/bin/ls'))
console.log(isExec('/dev/random'))
```

which should be doing all those checks for us.

Answer (score 2):

In Node the `fs.stat` method returns an `fs.Stats` object, you can get the file permission through the fs.Stats.mode property.  From this post: [Nodejs File Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775884/nodejs-file-permissions)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/executable it even has a .sync() method

```
executable('bash').then(exec => {
    console.log(exec);
    //=> true 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This version is a little more fully featured. But it does rely on either `which` or `where`, which are os specific. This covers Windows and Posix (Mac, Linux, Unix, Windows if Posix layer exposed or Posix tools installed).

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const child = require("child_process");

function getExecPath(exec) {
  let result;
  try {
    result = child.execSync("which " + exec).toString().trim();
  } catch(ex) {
    try {
      result = child.execSync("where " + exec).toString().trim();
    } catch(ex2) {
      return;
    }
  }
  if (result.toLowerCase().indexOf("command not found") !== -1 ||
      result.toLowerCase().indexOf("could not find files") !== -1) {
    return;
  }
  return result;
}    


function isExec(exec) {
  if (process.platform === "win32") {
    switch(Path.GetExtension(exec).toLowerCase()) {
      case "exe": case "bat": case "cmd": case "vbs": case "ps1": {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  try {
    // Check if linux has execution rights
    fs.accessSync(exec, fs.constants.X_OK);
    return true;
  } catch(ex) {
  }
  // Exists on the system path
  return typeof(getExecPath(exec)) !== 'undefined';
}
```

Comment: That `child.execSync` call doesn't look safe to me, surely an attacker could supply a value for `exec` which allows it to execute arbitrary code on your computer. That's not desirable. Is there any other way to check for that?

Comment: yes. that level of sanitation should happen at your rest endpoint. or whatever mechanism you are using before this gets called. Otherwise, an attacker would have access to the command prompt. And finding this script to call it with node wouldn't be necessary. Also note: this may be more towards an earlier version of node. Deno (node replacement) has easier, more secure ways to do this.