# Unable to run my first node.js program?

Tags: node.js

I opened a text file on desktop.In that file I wrote

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Then I saved the file with name example.js and when i type
    node example.js
this error gets printed

```
 Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\example.js'
 at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
 at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
 at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
 at startup (node.js:119:16)
 at node.js:902:3
```

What am I doing wrong here the file example.js is on Desktop

Comment: You code worked for me on a Mac. Check your node version and file permissions and such. What you have looks correct, and looks like it should work.

Comment: Could you ty running `node`, then type `require("./example.js");`? And in another dir?

Comment: @TruePS Can you add how you resolved it as an accepted answer?  Or just delete the question if it was something trivial that others aren't likely to encounter.

Comment: @TruePS, you mentioned that example.js is on Desktop.  Did you cd to Desktop directory before typing "node example.js"

Comment: May be a silly question, but is your file an actual JS file and not example.js.txt?

Comment: Did you install nodejs?

Comment: @moathhowari yes i installed it.

Comment: @kelz no it is `example.js` not `example.js.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please firstly check node js is installed or not.open a terminal window and type
`node -v`.
Also you should check nodejs file permissions.You can use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775884/nodejs-file-permissions) for that.If problem persists kindly try to reinstall nodejs.You should try to install nodejs globally to run your program from anywhere.

Comment: Thanks very much i resolved the issue using your help.Thank you once again.

Answer (score 3):

I created a file named `example.js` on my desktop, ran it with `node example.js` and it worked.
Then I created the same file but its type was text `example.js.txt` - I got your very same result as shown below:

[image]

Is this the case?

Comment: That's what I said, is that I tried to reproduce the error. And I got it after running a file named `example.js.txt`

Comment: No my file name is `example.js`

Answer (score 0):

@TruePS Please verify that the file you have created has `.js` extension, as pointed out by @kelz

I guess your file has `.txt` extension, as you are saying *"I opened a text file on desktop"*

Try `node example.txt` if it is `.txt`. (as workaround)

`Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)` occurs when filename doesn't match.