# What's the most portable way to test if a directory is writable in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

A friend asked me this question and I gave de-facto two options.

First way, testing the file permissions:

```
//adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775884/nodejs-file-permissions#answer-11781404
var fs = require('fs')

function canWrite(directory) {
 var stat = fs.statSync(directory)

 // 2 is the octal value for chmod -w-
 return !!( 2 & (stat.mode & parseInt('777', 8)).toString(8)[0] ) //first char is the owner
}
```

What if the user (`process.uid`) was not the file system owner (`stat.uid`) neither in it's group (`process.gid vs stat.gid`)? 
It will still get the `644` permissions and writing will not be possible.

How may we actually know (with nodejs) that the current user belongs to the file system group (`stat.gid`)? [Easy in **bash**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14104522/1145578) but to be portable it'd be a mess with nodejs.

Second way, lazy:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var canWrite = true

try {
  fs.writeFileSync('./test')
  fs.unlinkSync('./test')
} catch(e) {
  canWrite = false
}

if(canWrite) {
 //go for it
}
```

Lazy solution of couse, but it should do the job. This could also block the kernel buffer. On the other side, `fs.Stat` is usually cached by operating systems.

Neither of these solution is perfect.

How would you do? Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What about:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.access(__dirname, fs.constants.W_OK, function(err) {
  if(err){
    console.error("can't write");
    process.exit(1);
  }

  console.log("can write");
  process.exit(0);
});
```

[Docs here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_access_path_mode_callback)

**`fs.constants.W_OK`** : File can be written by the **calling process**.

If you run the above with `sudo` you may get different outputs depending on user permissions.

Comment: Interesting thanks, here's the [commit](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/29449349da5ef7e23689396c21bae003d81e0081). 
`sudo` is not a portable thing.

Comment: Yeah, I just meant that it yields different results based on current permissions

Comment: Heads up that `fs` has been refactored -- `W_OK` now lives at `fs.constants.W_OK`.