# check (Windows) folder permissions using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I need to know how to find the permission to write in a specified folder, using NodeJs. (for the current user).

I have tried with

```
fs.access(path,fs.W_OK,function(err){})
```

and

```
fs.accessSync(path,fs.W_OK).
```

But, i am facing a TypeError, "Object has no method access".

I can do,

```
var stats = fs.statSync(path);
```

and get the details of a particular folder. Is there any method to find write permissions using the *stats* Object?

Any other solution is also appreciatable.

**Thanks in advance..**

Comment: Also an answer here. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/qmZtIwDRSYo

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775884/nodejs-file-permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775884/nodejs-file-permissions) I have tried this as well, but it doesn't help

Comment: stats.mode has the permissions.

Comment: lostintranslation, in the method you suggested, process.uid, process.gid is "undefined". Do i have to require anything?

Comment: stats.mode returns some value. But i don't know how to use that meaningfully?!

Answer (score 3):

You can examine the "mode" property of the returned object. The access permissions are as per traditional Unix access permissions, in groups of 3 bits.

```
var mode = fs.statSync(path).mode;
var writePermissions = mode & 0x92; // 010010010
```

Comment: for me, mode & 0x92 returns <b>146</b> for all paths

Comment: @SELVA Did you read the linked duplicate question? 144 means that write permission is allowed for all three access categories (owner, owning group, and world).

Comment: Here. i will try to explain my question more clearly. Multiple active  users available to my computer. Say, my user name is **myuser** and another one is **user1**.  
I can login with my user name, having access to this folder, `C:/users/user1` and could create a **.txt** file manually. But, if i try to write, using `fs.write(path,data,function(err){};)` it returns an error.
I am not able to find this issue.

Comment: I have no idea how Windows file permissions are represented via Node. The entire Node FileSystem API is directly modeled on the UNIX/Linux file system API.